# How can we retrieve/get the feature and scenario title in step definitions?

Tags: mstest, specflow, gherkin, scenarios

How can we retrieve/get feature, scenario title and tag name in step definitions?

For example I have a feature file booksearch with a feature:

```
Feature: Book Search
Scenario: Title should be matched

I perform a simple search on 'abc'
------------------------
------------------------


    [When(@"I perform a simple search on '(.*)'")]
    public void WhenIPerformASimpleSearchOn(string searchTerm)
    {
        --------
        ----------
        //custom log    
        WriteLogs(int stepNum,string scenarioName,string tagname,string stepDescription,string stepResult)
    }
```

How can we retrieve/get Feature and scenario title and tag name in step definitions for given scenario?

We are using MSTest as unit test provider.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can retrieve the feature and scenario title by querying the [FeatureInfo](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/FeatureContext/) and [ScenarioInfo](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/ScenarioContext/) classes.

For example, placing the following code in you step definition (i.e. WhenIPerformASimpleSearchOn() ):

```
var featureTitle = FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Title;
var featureTags  = FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Tags;
var featureDescription = FeatureContext.Current.FeatureInfo.Description;    

var scenarioTitle = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Title;
var scenarioTags  = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags;
```

Will retrieve the feature title, tags and description as well as the scenario title and tags.

Comment: How to do same thing in ruby ?

Answer (score 1):

They are part of the context, you'll probably need to look at both the [ScenarioContext](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/ScenarioContext/) and the 
[FeatureContext](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/FeatureContext/) to get the details you want.